# Rails: How to display certain characters and dismiss the rest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I use

```
<%= current_user.name[0,20] %>
```

it only shows 20 character, as I want.

However, I want to use this approach in another context. I have

```
<%= @patient.human_attribute_value(:complaints).html_safe %>
```

and I want to display only [0,20] characters of this, but I didn't manage. 
I tried

```
<%= @patient.human_attribute_value(:complaints[0,20]).html_safe %>
```

but it gives me an error.

Can you please help me?

Comment: See also the String#truncate method which Rails monkey-patches into String.  You may find it does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your context `:complaints` is a symbol that is sent as parameter. Why do you treat it as a property that returns a value?

Try

```
<%= @patient.human_attribute_value(:complaints)[0,20].html_safe %>
```